# firefox .aspxauth cookie not working

Tags: .net, firefox, cookies, .aspxauth

I'm working with .net and when i do forms authentication and set the cookie (.aspxauth) domain **".domain.com"** it works in all browsers except FireFox (v11).

the cookie is successfully saved and  is validated for **subdomain.domain.com** but for some reason it seems that firefox is not recognizing/finding it when i'm on the top level **domain.com**

problem also seems to exist in google chrome

how to get around this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

> You'll likely find that in fact most sites are using some combination of Set-Cookie from the older RFC spec with "Host" values, implicitly without a leading dot (as twitter.com does) or setting Domain values (with a leading dot) and redirecting to a server like www.example.com (as google.com does).